# Text formatting in java

Tags: java, text-formatting

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestTokenReplacement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String message = "this/is/{bad}";
        map.put("bad", "good");
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(message, map.get("bad")));
    }
}
```

Expected output is : this/is/good
How can get to format the string to replace the string tokens from the Map?

Comment: https://jknack.github.io/handlebars.java/gettingStarted.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Using String

You can use [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) if you do not want to import an additional class like this

```
String message = "this/is/%s";
String.format(message, map.get("bad"));
```

Here you will define the variables you want to replace by using `%s`.

#### Using MessageFormat

You can also do it using `MessageFormat`, but you have to identify your variables with the index of the argument. i.e:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String message = "this/is/{0}";
map.put("bad", "good");
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(message, map.get("bad")));
```

**Output**

```
this/is/good
```

Comment: I want the string tokens from the message to be replaced.

Comment: @SriniKandula look at my answer for MessageFormat, it will replace, and give you your expected output. You can also do with just String.format.

Answer (score 1):

```
String message = "this/is/{0}";
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(message, map.get("bad")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the {bad} with an index i.e 0. If you look at the syntax for format, it is variable argument. Each number corresponds to argument that follows that pattern.

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String message = "this/is/{0}/{1}";
    map.put("bad", "good");
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(message, map.get("bad"),"sample"));
```

Also, if you want to use it exactly the way you have used, try using.
MapFormat.format(text, map)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/AtextformatsimilartoMessageFormatbutusingstringratherthannumerickeys.htm